# How to make custom action?

Tags: ros, action

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Console output from compilation:

```
-- Generating .msg files for action turtlebot3_console_controller/Motor 
/home/rozoalex/ros_catkin_ws/src/turtlebot3_console_controller/action/Motor.action
File "/home/rozoalex/ros_catkin_ws/src/turtlebot3_console_controller/action/Motor.action", line 6
float64 angle
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):

execute_process(/home/rozoalex/ros_catkin_ws/build/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh
"/usr/bin/python"
"/home/rozoalex/ros_catkin_ws/src/turtlebot3_console_controller/action/Motor.action"
"-o"
"/home/rozoalex/ros_catkin_ws/devel/share/turtlebot3_console_controller/msg")
returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/indigo/share/actionlib_msgs/cmake/actionlib_msgs-extras.cmake:67 (safe_execute_process)
turtlebot3_console_controller/CMakeLists.txt:63 (add_action_files)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/rozoalex/ros_catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/rozoalex/ros_catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

When I tried to make my own action, I got this. It says I had a syntax error, which I dont think there is.

Here is my Motor.action file ->

```
# This is an action definition file, which has three parts: the goal
# the result, and the feedback.
# Part 1: the goal.
#
# The angle in degree the robot to turn, sent by client main
float64 angle
---
# Part 2: the result, sent by action server unpon completion
#
# How much time used
duration time_elapsed
# How many updates thrown in total
uint32 updates_n
---
# Part 3: the feedback,to be sent periodically by server
#
# The amount of time elapsed from the start
duration time_elapsed
```

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274403/how-to-make-custom-action?/) by [rozoalex](https://answers.ros.org/users/31065/rozoalex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2017-10-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-10-28**:
I can't see anything you've posted. Can you edit your question?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-28**:
@rozoalex: *don't post images to show us text.*

Copy-paste the content of the files into your question text, select it and press the *Preformatted Text* button (the one with `101010` on it).

**Comment by [rozoalex](https://answers.ros.org/users/31065/rozoalex/) on 2017-10-28**:
Thanks! just edited it

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-10-30**:
Can you post your `CMakeLists.txt` file? I really can't see what the problem is, your `.action` file looks fine to me. Also try to rebuild your project removing `build` and `devel` directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @rozoalex,

The error is "probably" on your `CMakeLists.txt`, but since it wasn't provided, I'll show you the steps to `make custom action` from zero (which can be useful for more people), as [shown in this video](https://youtu.be/_YckBpMna7A).

Since the name of your package is `turtlebot3_console_controller` and the action name is `Motor.action`, we are going to use the same names for simplicity.

1. Create the Catkin Workspace:

---

```
mkdir ~/catkin_ws/src/ -p
cd ~/catkin_ws/src/
catkin_init_workspace
```

2. Create your package named `turtlebot3_console_controller` that depends on the packages `actionlib_msgs` and `std_msgs`:

---

```
cd ~/catkin_ws/src/
catkin_create_pkg turtlebot3_console_controller actionlib_msgs std_msgs
```

3. Create the `Motor.action` on `turtlebot3_console_controller/action`:

---

```
cd ~/catkin_ws/src/
mkdir -p turtlebot3_console_controller/action
touch turtlebot3_console_controller/action/Motor.action
```

4. Add to `Motor.action` the content provided on the question:

---

```
# This is an action definition file, which has three parts: the goal
# the result, and the feedback.
# Part 1: the goal.
#
# The angle in degree the robot to turn, sent by client main
float64 angle
---
# Part 2: the result, sent by action server unpon completion
#
# How much time used
duration time_elapsed
# How many updates thrown in total
uint32 updates_n
---
# Part 3: the feedback,to be sent periodically by server
#
# The amount of time elapsed from the start
duration time_elapsed
```

5. Change `add_action_files` and `generate_messages` from `turtlebot3_console_controller/CMakeLists.txt` to be able to compile the action file. At the end, the `CMakeLists.txt` will be like we have below:

---

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(turtlebot3_console_controller)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  actionlib_msgs
  std_msgs
)

add_action_files(
   FILES
   Motor.action
)

generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
   actionlib_msgs#   std_msgs
)

catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES turtlebot3_console_controller
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS actionlib_msgs std_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

6. Compile your package:

---

```
cd ~/catkin_ws/src/
catkin_make
```

Ok, now your custom action should be compiled.

To confirm it was compiled, you can create a test file named `node.py` that just imports your custom action by following the steps below:

7. Create your test file named `node.py`:

---

```
cd ~/catkin_ws/src/
touch turtlebot3_console_controller/src/node.py
```

8. Add the content below to `node.py`:

---

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from turtlebot3_console_controller.msg import MotorGoal, MotorResult, MotorFeedback

print 'Ok, it worked!!!'
```

9. Run your `node.py` to confirm your custom action was compiled without any problem.

---

```
rosrun turtlebot3_console_controller node.py
```

After running `node.py` you should seee the message "`Ok, it worked!!!`".

In the [video](https://youtu.be/_YckBpMna7A) mentioned at the beginning we just follow the steps described here.

Hope it helps.

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) with karma: 1038 on 2017-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2